# firestore rules compare request data with data in db

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a data structure like this:

Collection: general
Document: users_list

```
{  
  jkkjhj877: {  
    name: Tom,
    points: 5
  },
  876tzuizt: {
    name: Bella,
    points: 8
  }
}
```

I want to allow read for every user and update only for the user with the matching id.
Therefore I need to compare the whole input request with the document from firestore.
It would be best to create a map with all the users except of the one which can be updated and then compare if they match. With that I can make sure no other user will be update.

As far as I've seen there is no function like delete for a map or even possibilities to loop through a map. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore rules act on a document, and you cannot create rules based on a specific field of a document. If you want to only allow writes to one specific element while allowing read access to the rest, [using subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections) instead of maps is more suitable for your use case.